# What is wrong with my TUIO 1.1 bundle code?

Tags: python, web-services, unity-game-engine

I am interested in sending a TUIO bundle over a network and receiving it on the Unity side. Unity won't recognize the bundle, so I am assuming something is wrong with it.

```
(while sent every .1 seconds)
    send_address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x', 3333

    # OSC basic client
    c = OSC.OSCClient()
    c.connect( send_address ) # set the address for all following messages
    bundle = OSC.OSCBundle()
    bundle.append( {'addr':"/tuio/2Dcur", 'args':["source:", "Py@Unity.com"]} ) # and some more stuff ...
    bundle.append( {'addr':"/tuio/2Dcur", 'args':["alive:", 21]} ) # and some more stuff ...
    bundle.append( {'addr':"/tuio/2Dcur", 'args':["set:", 21, 0.328125, 0.6529948115348816, 0, 0, -2.5432088375091553]} ) # and some more stuff ...
    bundle.setAddress("/tuio/2Dcur")
    c.send(bundle) # send it!
```

Comment: Have you tried printing to console in unity to see what its receiving..?

Comment: Well Unity's Touchscript is kind of confusing, and I am wondering where is receives it.
I do have a console application that I can test which shows the same message from TUIOpad and that.

Comment: So are you receiving anything in unity..? Can show the receiver script?